# Forward function calls to underlying data in a wrapper template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a template wrapper, something like this

```
template<class T>
class Wrapper{
public:
    Wrapper(T data);
    ~Wrapper();

    void doSomeWrapperWork();

private:
    T data;
};
```

If I want to access the wrapped data, I can obviously add a getter function that returns a reference to the data. I was wondering however if there is anyway, with some template magic, to call directly on the wrapper functions of the underlying wrapped data. In other words, if I have a class `TestObject` with a public function `void foo()`, I would like to be able to call it in this way:

```
Wrapper<TestObject> myWrapper;
myWrapper.foo();
```

instead of:

```
myWrapper.getData().foo();
```

without knowing a priori that such a function exists. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite, until C++ gets reflection we can't easily write wrapper classes without a lot of boilerplate macros

**but**

You can add an implicit conversion of your wrapper class to `T`:

```
template<class T>
class Wrapper{
public:
    Wrapper(T data_) : data(data_) {}

    operator const T&() const
    {
        return data;
    }

private:
    T data;
};
```

And now your class is convertible to `T`, so we can call a method on `T`, with a little work:

usage:

```
struct Foo
{
    constexpr int bar() const
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr Foo f;
    Wrapper<Foo> my_wrapper(f);
    static_assert(static_cast<const Foo&>(my_wrapper).bar() == 42);
}
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mcSAaK3dg2W6gOf7)

---

If you want to avoid the casting yourself, you can write a free function that will call your function, so that implicit conversion may take over:

```
int call_bar(const Foo& f)
{
    return f.bar();
}
```

Usage:

```
Foo f;
Wrapper<Foo> my_wrapper(f);
std::cout << call_bar(my_wrapper); // 42
```

### [Demo2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oKZ6Z36sLrnog5gR)

I kind of like this approach as all it requires is that we add a free function for each wrapped function we want instead of having to manually do a bunch of casting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try something like

```
#include <iostream>
struct TestObject{
    void foo() { std::cout << "TestObject" << std::endl;}
};

template <class T>
struct Wrapper : public T{
    Wrapper() {}
    void doSomeWrapperWork() {}
};

int main() {
    Wrapper<TestObject> wrapper;
    wrapper.foo();
}
```

This allows you to add more functionality as need while still allowing the wrapper to be used as a class T.

This is inspired by the decorator design pattern.